# Sort and Remove unused usings in C# code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to **Sort** and **Remove Unused** `usings` in C# just like in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017?

If not, could this be an addition to a future Visual Studio Code version?

Comment: Please note that your second question is off-topic here: this is not a forum for making feature requests to any third-party product.

Comment: @IMSoP In a way I agree with you but on the other hand even MSFT recommends to ask here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new (See the message). I was going to create an Issue. I have seen this not only with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What Microsoft says on an external site does not over-ride the policies of this site. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support In this case, your first question seems absolutely fine, but if the answer is "no, there's no way in the current version", the feature request to add it will need to be raised as an issue elsewhere.

Comment: @IMSoP, sure, if there is none then I will create an Issue on Github. That was my initial idea. I just could not find a way anywhere to do this with Visual Studio Code so I wanted to clarify before I create an Issue.

Comment: Try install Beautify extension. Hover on using keyword and you get an yellow bulb icon and click on that you can see a context menu "remove unused namespaces".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a command that is built into vscode to help out removing unused usings.

The default keybinding is defined as:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+.", "command": "editor.action.quickFix",
                      "when": "editorHasCodeActionsProvider && 
                               editorTextFocus && 
                               !editorReadonly" },
```

As for sorting the usings: I did not find anything built explicitly for using statements, but there is a command to sort lines. Add something similar to the following into your keybindings file:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+q", "command": "editor.action.sortLinesAscending",
                      "when": "editorFocus && !editorReadonly" },
```

Then, select the using statements and press ctrl+q to sort them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of extensions available now in Visual Studio Code that can help with this:

Name: **C# Sort Usings**
Id: jongrant.csharpsortusings
Description: Sort using statements
Version: 0.0.6
Publisher: Jon Grant
VS Marketplace Link: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jongrant.csharpsortusings\](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jongrant.csharpsortusings%5C)

Name: **C# Format Usings**
Id: gaoshan0621.csharp-format-usings
Description: Sort C# using statements and remove unnecessary usings
Version: 0.0.4
Publisher: Shan Gao
VS Marketplace Link: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gaoshan0621.csharp-format-usings\](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gaoshan0621.csharp-format-usings%5C)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these extensions seem to offer a "execute on save" setting.